# Upgrade Ubuntu: What are the consequences of the decision hold old grub config or not?

Tags: boot, grub2, upgrade, uefi

Upgrade of Ubuntu to the currently most recent version: What are the consequences of the decision hold old grub config or not?
I have decided to hold the old grub config.
As a result, the Windows entries still exist in the UEFI multiboot menu.
The Ubuntu entry however has gone.
Was would have been the result when I had chosen not to hold the old grub config?

Comment: By holding old config, you preserve any boot instruction that you may have previously customised, so it is usually safest to do that. Your machine should boot to GRUB and not to UEFI me thinks. Did you change anything in the UEFI menus?

Answer (score 0):

I have chosen to hold the old grub.
When booting, still the device boot entries are displayed at first.
Windows dual boot still entries are still accessible from the displayed entry.
However, the Ubuntu entry is missing.
As a consequence, Ubuntu Minotaur on disk is not bootable.
There must something horribly went wrong (see figures below).
[image]

[image]